# Counting elements of certain orders in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to answer the following exercise:

How many elements of order $4$ does $S_6$ have? How many elements of
 order $2$ does $S_6$ have?

> Please could you tell me if my answer is correct?

Here is my work on elements of order $4$:

Note that the only elements of order $4$ are $4$-cycles. Therefore we just need to count (unique) $4$-cycles. Two cycles are the same if and only if one can be obtained from the other by "rotating" the digits. The number of $4$-cycles that can be obtained by "rotating" digits is $4$.

In total there are $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$ four cycles. But here we have counted $4$-times too many. To eliminate the duplicates we divide by $4$.

Therefore  there are $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 = 90$ elements of order $4$ in $S_6$.

---

Elements of order two can either occur as $2$-cycles or as products of $2$-cycles of the form $(ab)(cd)$.

The number of unique $2$-cycles is $6 \cdot 5 / 2 = 15$.

The number of unique products $(ab)(cd)$ is $15 \cdot 15$.

Hence in total there are $16 \cdot 15 = 240$ elements of order $2$ in $S_6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking in terms of products of disjoint cycles is very good start.

*Order 4:* Beside $4$-cycles like $(1234)$, which you counted correctly, we need to also take account of products like $(1234)(56)$. That doubles your count.

*Order $2$:* The number of $2$-cycles is right. There are $\frac{1}{2!}\binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{2}$ products of two disjoint $2$-cycles. Another way of counting shows there are $\binom{6}{4}(3)$.

You also need to count the products of three disjoint $2$-cycles. That is left to you. Please leave a message if you are unsure of how many there are.

Comment: Thank you so much. While thinking about this some more (before I saw your answer) I also came to the conclusion that I have to count products of three two cycles. I will post my updated solution in the comments here.

Comment: I count $180$ elements of order $4$ and 195 of order $2$. Is that correct? The second number I got as there are 15 transpositions, 15 times 6 equals 90 disjoint products of two transpositions and another 90 disjoint products of three transpositions.

Comment: And I just found another mistake: I should only get $75$ disjoint products of transpositions as they commute. And then we get $165$ elements of order two. Is that correct?

Comment: Order $2$:  $15$ transpositions, $45$ disjoint products of two transpositions, and $15$ disjoinf products of three, total $75$.  Your $90$ overcounts the products of three by a factor of $3!$.

Comment: Okay, $3$ times $15$ is $45$, not $75$ >.< Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.